# javascript regex split

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to split a string twice with regex? For example, say I have the string:

```
example=email@address.com|fname|lname
```

how can I split to the result is:

```
email@address.com,fname,lname
```

thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually remove the prefix:

```
str.substr(str.indexOf('=') + 1)
   .split('|')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var result=myString.split("=", 2)[1].split("|");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to search and replace the '|' to ' , '.

Why dont you use `replace()`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp